# awk difference between Linux & Solaris

Tags: variables, awk, solaris-10

Need small help with AWK.

Following command works in Linux but doesn't work in Solaris, Any thoughts would be very helpful.

```
cat module-list.txt | \
  awk -v MODULE=${MODULE} -v OSNAME=${OSName} -v OSPLATFORM=${OSPlatform} \
    '{if ($1 == MODULE && $5 == OSNAME && (NF == 5 || $6 == OSPLATFORM)) {print $2}}' | \
  wc -l
```

Thanks,
Vamshi .D

Comment: Exactly which `awk` on Solaris are you using?  There are three or four different versions available on a standard Solaris installation.

Comment: Consider removing the superfluous `cat module-list.txt` and place the filename after the `awk` script. Secondly, if all you want to do is count the lines, count them in `awk` -  no need for `wc`. Try using the `awk` under `/usr/xpg4/bin` or wherever they keep that one nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

Try on a Solaris/SunOS system, change `awk` to `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` or `/usr/xpg6/bin/awk` , or `nawk`. Though they have few differences in them but you will not get the infamous

> bail out syntax error

which we will be getting while using only `awk` in Sun systems.
Fair warning, in lack of sample Input_file didn't test anything for code.